# default and implicit arguments in boost program options

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I am seeing some strange behavior with boost program_options.  I have an option that has a [default and implicit value](https://github.com/COMBINE-lab/salmon/blob/master/src/SalmonQuantify.cpp#L2001).  To make a widely-compatible binary of my program, I compile it under [Holy Build Box](http://phusion.github.io/holy-build-box/), which seems to work well.  However, the problem I'm encountering is that when I provided this pre-compiled executable with an explicit argument for this option (i.e. `--writeMappings ./somefile.txt`) the result is parsed incorrectly.  Rather than mapping the argument `./somefile.txt` to the option `--writeMappings`, boost::program_options thinks that the argument to the `--writeMappings` option is empty, and there is another option, the empty string `""` that has an argument of `./somefile.txt`.

I store the variable map in a JSON file, and the example [here](https://github.com/COMBINE-lab/salmon/issues/86#issuecomment-244808134) demonstrates exactly the behavior I'm seeing.  Does anyone have an idea why this might occur?  I assume that it's not the correct behavior.  Strangely, when I compile the same code *outside* of Holy Build Box (using g++-4.9.1 instead of g++-4.8.2), the program works as expected, and the implicit argument is overridden by any explicit argument that is passed.

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  using std::cerr;
  using std::string;
  namespace po = boost::program_options;
  string fname;
  po::options_description generic("\n"
                                  "basic options");
  generic.add_options()("version,v", "print version string")
   (
   "writeMappings", po::value<string>(&fname)->default_value("")->implicit_value("-"),
   "If this option is provided, then the quasi-mapping results will be written out in SAM-compatible "
   "format.  By default, output will be directed to stdout, but an alternative file name can be "
   "provided instead.");
  po::options_description visible("options");
  visible.add(generic);


  po::variables_map vm;
  try {
    auto orderedOptions =
        po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(visible).run();

    po::store(orderedOptions, vm);
    po::notify(vm);
    std::cerr << "writeMappings = " << fname << '\n';
  } catch (po::error& e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception : [" << e.what() << "]. Exiting.\n";
    std::exit(1);
  }
return 0;
}
```

I compiled with the following:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o opttest main.cpp -L /home/boost_1_61_0/lib -I /home/boost_1_61_0/include -lboost_program_options
```

and I get the following output with the corresponding invocations:

```
  $ ./opttest
  writeMappings = 
  $ ./opttest --writeMappings
  writeMappings = -
  $ ./opttest --writeMappings stuff
  writeMappings = -
```

The final invocation is the problematic one.  Given the explicit option, I'd expect `writeMappings = stuff`.  I will note, however, that when I use alternative syntax, it gets parsed correctly:

```
  $ ./opttest --writeMappings=stuff
  writeMappings = stuff
```

However, I'd really like this to work with the more common `--option argument` syntax.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], with the code directly in the question.

Comment: Ok, I've provided a mcve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html#idp72934416-bb), emphasis mine:

> ```
> typed_value * implicit_value(const T & v);
> ```
>
> Specifies an implicit value, which will be used if the option is given, but without an adjacent value. Using this implies that an explicit value is optional, but if given, **must be strictly adjacent to the option**, i.e.: '-ovalue' or '--option=value'. Giving '-o' or '--option' will cause the implicit value to be applied.

So when you write:

```
$ ./opttest --writeMappings stuff
```

`stuff` isn't strictly adjacent to the option `writeMappings`, so is interpreted as a separate option entirely. You will have to write:

```
$ ./opttest --writeMappings=stuff
```

to get the value of `"stuff"` instead of `"-"`.

Comment: Wow — I can't believe I missed that.  Strangely, this means that the result produced in my alternative environment where `$ ./opttest --writeMappings stuff` produces `writeMappings = stuff` is actually unexpected behavior, right? I can't explain that other than that unexpected behavior is . . . *unexpected*.  Thank's for the quick reply.